# Ninject implementation in Window Forms - C#

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0, ninject, ninject-2

**I am using Window Forms C# with Ninject version: 2.0.0.1**

First Installed the Ninject Package : `ninject.extensions.infrastructure.winforms`

Second I created the new class with following code.

```
public class CustomModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IDAL.IORDR>().To<DAL.DAL_ORDR>();
    }
}
```

Third in the window form I did below

```
public partial class SODetails : Form
{
    public IORDR _IORDR { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public SODetails(IORDR ORDR)
    {
        _IORDR = ORDR;
    }

    public SODetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Finally in the Program.cs, I did the below code

```
static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    var kernel = new StandardKernel(new CustomModule());
    var form = kernel.Get<SODetails>();
    Application.Run(form);
}
```

***Although I am able to Inject the dependencies successfully but the form is not showing any control. Am I doing the Ninject implementation in wrong way ?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the following code from

```
public partial class SODetails : Form
{
    public IORDR _IORDR { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public SODetails(IORDR ORDR)
    {
        _IORDR = ORDR;
    }

    public SODetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

to

```
public partial class SODetails : Form
{
    public IORDR _IORDR { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public SODetails(IORDR ORDR)
    {
        _IORDR = ORDR;
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public SODetails()
    {
```

<s>InitializeComponent();</s>

```
    }
}
```

Comment: alright ... u have called InitializeComponent() from both the constructors. Any specific reason for not using constructor chaining ?

Comment: Dependency Injection will never let me call the default constructor.

Comment: Certainly..  if you call the default constructor directly you'll never get the chance to inject dependency.

Comment: My point is not to call default constructor directly from program.cs but to make a constructor chaining and avoid duplication.  So program  calls constructor with dependency & that constructor calls the default constructor  -  'SODetails(IORDR ORDR) : this()'.  This will prevent you from duplicating the function call of InitializeComponent() in both the constructors

Comment: Its  valid for the sample code you pasted here. Anyway, whatever works for u

Comment: In this main class, an instance of Kernal is created in the Main method. Do we really need to create an instance of the kernel in every time we inject a dependency? @Pankaj

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem.

So your SODetails form is up and running but it doesnt show any controls on it that you have added in designer . I'm I correct ?

The issue is the InitializeComponent() is not called.

Please change the code, so as to call the default constructor & all will work fine. 
I made a small change to your code for constructor chaining        public SODetails(IORDR ORDR) : this()
{....}

```
public IORDR _IORDR { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public SODetails(IORDR ORDR) : this()
    {
        _IORDR = ORDR;
    }

    public SODetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    public IORDR _IORDR { get; set; }

    [Inject]
    public SODetails(IORDR ORDR) : this()
    {
        _IORDR = ORDR;
    }

    public SODetails()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```